# App Store Analytics: 10,000 Downloads in one day with Only 3 Product Page Views?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, mac-appstore, app-store-connect

I recently noticed an anomaly in my app store analytics on [Appstore Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/).

Despite previously having no downloads, there was a sudden spike of over 10,000 downloads in a single day.

[image: Download Statistics]

However, that's not the main concern.

Upon checking the "Product Page view" statistics, which Apple defines as:

> The number of times the app's product page was viewed on the App Store on devices running iOS 8, tvOS 9, macOS 10.14.1, or later.

I observed that on the very day I had these 10K+ downloads, there were only *3* product page views.

[image: Product Page Views]

**How can there be over 10,000 downloads with only 3 product page views?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After some investigation, I've determined the cause of the significant discrepancy in my App Store analytics: An [MDM (Mobile Device Management)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_management) service was responsible for deploying my app.

For clarity, MDM services can directly push apps to numerous managed devices, bypassing the traditional method of accessing the App Store's product page. This means that an organization or institution equipped with an MDM service decided to deploy my app across their devices. This resulted in the spike of downloads without a corresponding increase in product page views.

Comment: Well, all's well that ends well. Well done for figuring it out - & congrats on 10,000 new users :)

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks!
Just wondering: Do you think it makes sense that I asked this question on _Ask different_ rather than _StackOverflow_?

Comment: @MendelG I think this is probably the more appropriate forum for this question. It's not really about programming (it's about selling your program after it's written), and it's very Apple-specific.

Comment: Connect is specifically [on topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so no problem with this.

Comment: An organization deploying your app across a network of 10K devices, wow!

Comment: Yup @Barmar . If only it was a _paid_ app :)

Comment: @MendelG if you have a contact at the org, maybe you could reach out and see if they want some kind of deal where they can contact you directly if their users have a problem or if the company needs features added to the app (for a fee of course)

Comment: If this is a free app, can you create a paid (pro) version that has some more functionality ? That will catch the eyes of the org that downloads your FREE version 10K times.